# AWS CLI in WSL2: "RequestTimeTooSkewed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I execute the command:  `aws s3 ls` and got the following error message:

> An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.

Please advise.

Comment: Some of your internal clocks are wrong. Either your windows and / or your linux time are not correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WSL, you can run `wsl --shutdown` in CMD or PowerShell. This ensures the next time you start a WSL session, it cold boots and fixes the time.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245

Answer (score 0):

AWS API requests are 'signed' and part of the information exchanged is a timestamp. If the timestamp is more than 900 seconds old the request will be rejected.

This is done to prevent "replay attacks" where old requests are sent again.

You can fix this by correcting the Date and Time on the system where you are sending the request.